# HTTP Error:502(Bad Gateway) when pushing to google code repositories using tortoiseHg

Tags: tortoisehg, proxy-server

As stated in the title,
I have done some search, but still cannot fix the problem. But previously, I can push without any problems, after a few weeks, when I try to push something, it gives me 502 bad gateway error. I guess there might be some problem related to server??

Mercurial Distributed SCM

TortoiseHg version 2.9

Windows 8

Thanks

Comment: Mercurial version is 2.7

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Google code repos use a 502 response when they have taken sections of the service down to make changes to the SVN that they use.

The google code blog and forums are very good at documenting these. The fastest way to check if there was an outage is to search for it on the forums however as the blog does not show all outage information.

Google code - blog http://googledevelopers.blogspot.co.uk/